How do I create a List Section based on an empty related field in SwiftData?
I have three models in SwiftData - a parent Event related to Group and Item. I have a list of all Items by Group that belong to a specific Event. But I can't figure out how to list the Items that belong to a specific Event that aren't associated with a Group.
MODELS
@Model
class Event: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var groups: [Group]?
    var items: [Item]?
}

@Model
class Group: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Event.groups) var group: Group?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var items: [Item]?

}

@Model
class Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var notes: String = ""
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Event.items) var event: Event?
    @Relationship(inverse: \Group.items) var group: Group?
}

I'm using a query to assign the Groups without an Event to a variable and then building a list off that:
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Group>{ ($0.event == nil) }) private var looseGroups: [Group]
But when I try that to identify Items without a Group, I am having trouble limiting them to a specific Event. If I use the same query, I get all items across all Events, rather than the specific one I want.
I've tried a sort of cascade logic first getting items where Group == nil and then getting event.items:
if item.groups == nil {
                    ForEach(event.items!.sorted(by: {$0.status < $1.status}))

But this causes errors further up in the first ForEach in the list:
Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Section<EmptyView, TupleView<(some View, some View)>, EmptyView>' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
Is there a way to do this sort of stacked logic to create a list of the Items in a specific Event but not associated with any Groups?
Thank you.

What is your question about really, how to write such predicate or how to write the code for the UI?
